# Production function problem (Lagrange multiplier)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, economics

I want to solve this production function using Lagrange multiplier

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{} \quad & U(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}})^{\frac{1}{\rho}} \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_{i}x_{i}=I}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

## What I have been doing

### Apply lagrangian

$$L(x_i, \lambda)=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}})^{\frac{1}{\rho}} - \lambda(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_{i}x_{i} - I})$$

### Finding the FOCs

$$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\lambda}} = I - \sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_{i}x_{i}}$$
$$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{x_i}} = \frac{\theta_k x_k^\rho(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}})^{\frac{1}{\rho}})}{x_k(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}})} - \lambda p_k$$
[Process here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyhPr.jpg)

### Why can't it be solved this way?

I've been reading and found that in order to solve this problem you have to find a **growing monotone function** to simplify the utility function.

$$v(x)=U(x)^\rho $$
$$\max_{} \quad v(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}}$$

*There would be how to work with the long line?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, maximizing $U(x)$ and $U(x)^p$ would be equivalent. The second case is much easier though: if you write the problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{} \quad & U(x)^p = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\theta_{i}x_{i}^{\rho}} \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_{i}x_{i}=I}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
then the optimality conditions are:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\theta_i \rho x_i^{\rho-1} - \lambda p_i = 0 \quad \forall i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i = I
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Injecting the first one into the second one, we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \left(\frac{\lambda p_i}{\theta_i} \right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} = I
\end{equation}
then solve for $\lambda$ and inject back in the first equation.

Comment: How could it be solved in the long form (image)?